# How to take results from a query based the column names another query produces

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure if that title makes a lot of sense. This question is a more in depth question relating to one i asked earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262938/how-to-select-row-values-as-another-tables-column-names/55263180?noredirect=1#comment97259053_55263180)

Our software has an execution log and i was able to capture this beefy query.
Basically it pulls all the columns possible but only the few rows that are needed to view. then some how the software only shows the columns in the view the user has saved. i want to take the result from this beefy query to only show the columns that match this other query:

```
SELECT *
FROM list_config
WHERE list_config.config_name = 'username'
  AND list_config.visible = 'Y';
```

the beefy one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       wo.id AS wo_id,
       wo.create_date,
       wo.priority,
       wo.activity_status_id,
       wo.short_description,
       wo.ops_note,
       CONVERT(varchar(1000), task.description) AS description,
       customer.customer_name,
       customer.account_manager,
       task.id AS task_id,
       wo.type_of,
       CASE WHEN wo.type_of = 'R' THEN 'Request' WHEN wo.type_of = 'P' THEN 'Project' END AS type_descr,
       wo.project_class_id,
       CASE WHEN (task.ovr_bill_status IS NOT NULL) THEN task.ovr_bill_status ELSE task.bill_status END AS bill_status,
       wo.customer_id,
       customer.support_who,
       customer.programmer,
       customer.proj_manager,
       customer.customer_class,
       customer.date_go_live,
       customer.within_golive_days,
       wo.resp_user_id,
       task.plan_hours AS plan_hours,
       task.actual_hours AS actual_hours,
       task.plan_start_date AS plan_start_date,
       task.plan_finish_date AS plan_finish_date,
       wo.release_id,
       customer.timezone,
       wo.update_date,
       wo.grouping_id,
       wo.grouping_id2,
       users.avail_status AS acct_manager_available
FROM task,
     work_order AS wo
     LEFT OUTER JOIN customer ON wo.customer_id = customer.code_id
                             AND customer.company_id = 'MCLD'
     LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = customer.account_manager
                          AND users.company_id = 'MCLD',
     assignment
WHERE task.company_id = 'MCLD'
  AND wo.status <> 'V'
  AND task.status <> 'C'
  AND assignment.is_complete = 'N'
  AND wo.customer_id NOT IN ('ZZZZ')
  AND task.work_order_id = wo.id
  AND wo.company_id = 'MCLD'
  AND task.id = assignment.task_id
  AND wo.id = assignment.work_order_id
  AND assignment.assigned_user_id IN ('SLSSVC')
  AND assignment.company_id = 'MCLD'
ORDER BY wo.create_date;
```

here are all the columns in the table list_config  done by select the top 1000

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [company_id]
  ,[column_width]
  ,[config_name]
  ,[field_name]
  ,[grid_name]
  ,[sequence]
  ,[visible]
  ,[column_alignment]
  ,[config_owner]
  ,[sort_order]
  ,[grid_odd_row_color]
  ,[sort_sequence]
  ,[grid_even_row_color]
```

FROM [list_config]

Comment: White space and line break are really important to writting **readable** SQL. I suggest you start using it. :)

Comment: You can do this with either a join or a subquery, but you'll need to add the `list_config` table structure for an answer.  I am sure one of the tables in your main query has a column that can be used to check against one in `list_config`, but without table structure an answer is not possible.

Comment: You should really not be using ANSI-89 JOIN syntax either: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). "Normal" JOIN syntax has been around since 1992, so you've had 27 years to adopt it. :) `task.id = assignment.task_id` should not be in your `WHERE` it should be in the `ON` clause in your `INNER JOIN` (not implied `CROSS JOIN`) to `assignment`.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the columns for list_config in your other question, you should just be able to join `wo.customer_id` to `list_config.customer_id` and add your conditions from the smaller statement to the main one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       wo.id AS wo_id,
       wo.create_date,
       wo.priority,
       wo.activity_status_id,
       wo.short_description,
       wo.ops_note,
       CONVERT(varchar(1000), task.description) AS description,
       customer.customer_name,
       customer.account_manager,
       task.id AS task_id,
       wo.type_of,
       CASE WHEN wo.type_of = 'R' THEN 'Request' WHEN wo.type_of = 'P' THEN 'Project' END AS type_descr,
       wo.project_class_id,
       CASE WHEN (task.ovr_bill_status IS NOT NULL) THEN task.ovr_bill_status ELSE task.bill_status END AS bill_status,
       wo.customer_id,
       customer.support_who,
       customer.programmer,
       customer.proj_manager,
       customer.customer_class,
       customer.date_go_live,
       customer.within_golive_days,
       wo.resp_user_id,
       task.plan_hours AS plan_hours,
       task.actual_hours AS actual_hours,
       task.plan_start_date AS plan_start_date,
       task.plan_finish_date AS plan_finish_date,
       wo.release_id,
       customer.timezone,
       wo.update_date,
       wo.grouping_id,
       wo.grouping_id2,
       users.avail_status AS acct_manager_available
FROM task,
     work_order AS wo
     LEFT OUTER JOIN customer ON wo.customer_id = customer.code_id
                             AND customer.company_id = 'MCLD'
     LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = customer.account_manager
                          AND users.company_id = 'MCLD',
     assignment

-- added join here
JOIN list_config AS lc
ON wo.customer_id = lc.customer_id

WHERE task.company_id = 'MCLD'
  AND wo.status <> 'V'
  AND task.status <> 'C'
  AND assignment.is_complete = 'N'
  AND wo.customer_id NOT IN ('ZZZZ')
  AND task.work_order_id = wo.id
  AND wo.company_id = 'MCLD'
  AND task.id = assignment.task_id
  AND wo.id = assignment.work_order_id
  AND assignment.assigned_user_id IN ('SLSSVC')
  AND assignment.company_id = 'MCLD'

-- added conditions from smaller statement here
  AND lc.config_name = 'username'
  AND lc.visible = 'Y'

ORDER BY wo.create_date;
```

Comment: I wish that were the case but the results from that smaller query are the rows of the actual column names in the in the work_order table. im going to add the table structure of the list_config table

Comment: the column field_name is storing the names of the columns from the work_order table that i want to reduce  the results of the columns in the beefy query to only the listed column names in list_config. i hope that makes sense